# Running "npm run build" with specific env file

Tags: vue.js, npm, build, environment-variables

Whenever I run "npm run build" command, my vue project automatically use ".env.production" file(which is one of my .env files). I would like to build my project by specifying env files for example

1. npm run build .env.production (to deploy on production server)
2. npm run build .env.development (to deploy on development server)

Is there any way I can specify environment variables when running "npm run build"????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Environment Variables for Node to retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/setting-environment-variables-for-node-to-retrieve)

Comment: @MohammadMasoudi Thank you for the reply.. but that's not what I was looking for. I know how to set environment variables with .env files. What I am looking for is, how to run "npm run build" with specific .env files. That way I can create multiple builds with different .env filed..

Comment: what is your Vue version and do you use `webpack` or `Vue CLI` or `Vite` ?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudi I use Vue CLI

Comment: did you check out this link? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: @MohammadMasoudi Thank you so much !! I finally found a way thank you

Comment: your welcome, enjoy coding :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by run `npm run build --mode production --dest ./dist/production`

or

You can achieve this by edit package.json file and add the below run script.

when you add -- mode and --dest in the build command this will pass it to the build script and will look for the mentioned env

```
"build-production": "vue-cli-service build --mode production --dest ./dist/production",
```

This will take the environment variables from a file called .env.production if not found will search on file called .env

And will export the build in a dir called dist/production and you can change this from --dest part

Then you should run

```
npm run build-production
```

This will will run for production and you can make a second scrip and change to development to read from .env.development
Something like

```
"build-development": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --dest ./dist/development",
```