# Running Meteor Build under Node with settings argument

Tags: node.js, meteor, arguments, parameter-passing

Typically when developing I would use `meteor run --settings settings.json`. This works fine and can view the settings in the browser with `Meteor.settings` on the console.

I am now build for production, using `meteor build`, I've looked at the documentation and there is nowhere to add `settings` during the build process.

So the build runs and I have my `.tar.gz` file, it's loaded to production and then I untar/compress the folder and run the start script.

It enters the program with `npm start` and the package.json section looks like this (ignore the stop script);

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js --settings settings.json",
    "stop": "killall node"
  }
}
```

When I look at my app it is not collecting these settings. It is as if when bundled it doesn't expect the arguements. I also tried using forever beforehand, but I had no joy with this either.

Any help would appreciated, start to wish I never bothered with Meteor :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to [Meteor Guide > Production > Deployment and Monitoring > Environment variables and Settings](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#environment)

> **Settings**. These are in a JSON object set via either the `--settings` Meteor command-line flag or stringified into the `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable.

As for setting environment variables, if you use a 3rd party host, you may have a GUI or CLI to define them.

Otherwise, you should have plenty resources including on SO:

- [Node.js: Setting Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312671/node-js-setting-environment-variables)
- [How can I set an environmental variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829433/how-can-i-set-an-environmental-variable-in-node-js)
- https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/

In short, it should look like:

```
METEOR_SETTINGS='{"key":"value"}' node main.js
```

You can also try the bash `cat` command to extract the content of a file: `$(cat settings.json)`

Comment: Excellent! They need to go before node? (I was just looking at the cat option)

Comment: You don't happen to know how I can do this with forever while you here do ya :)

Comment: For the record, just found that example on Docs: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/meteor/4198/environment-detection/14700/specifying-app-parameters-with-meteor-settings (not sure it is in the appropriate topic though)

Comment: @ghybs after all these years, I'm still supporting a legacy meteor app and wanted to see an example of the meteor settings after the app as been converted to node.  The SO docs has been deactivated so I cannot see the example you referenced.  Any chance you can post it here/somewhere?

Comment: Hi @Aaron, not exactly sure what you need besides what is posted in the above answer? I do have some Meteor apps, and still use the above technique without any issue: `METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat /path/to/settingsProd.json)" node main.js` (in linux).

Comment: I was able to make a script after all.  Deploying the Docker/Meteor container to Azure.  Everything works nicely.  Thank you.